# does anyone know how to begin an unreal script?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm just stuck with unreal script, i mean i just want to write a class that logs down "i'm alive" when the game starts, dows any one know how can i do that? my ultimate goal is to extend a camera class but i just recieve `failed to load "class None."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using the documentation provided at UDK.com

[Your first UnrealScript project](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitFirstScriptProject.html)

There are also countless YouTube Tutorials

[YouTube UnrealScript Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unrealscript%20tutorial&aq=2&oq=unrealsc)

You can even pay for a professional tutorial like I did

[Eat3D UnrealScript Tutorial](http://eat3d.com/unrealscript)

There are also forums dedicated to this topic

[UDK Community Forums](http://forums.epicgames.com/forumdisplay.php?f=367)

Answer (score 0):

unrealscript is not something that you can learn compeletly. its big with lots of functionality. you have to write your documentation for gameplay and find the way to make them. there is just one book that is not based on "utgame" classes.
UnrealScript Game Programming Cookbook Paperback
by Dave Voyles
it helps
aftar that its best to read dungeon defence source codes to get upper level. i beleive udk documentation and forum dont help so much.